# Implementing MKMapView didRemoveAnnotationViews method?

Tags: objective-c, mkmapview

There's a method of MKMapViewDelegate protocol:

```
- (void)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView didAddAnnotationViews:(NSArray *)views
```

Which I'm using for custom pin dropping animations, though there's no method for "remove" (didRemoveAnnotationViews) action to implement custom animations when annotation views are being removed.

Has anyone figured out a workaround for that?

Thanks!

Comment: Do you mean you want an animation when you call removeAnnotation?  If yes, then before removing it, try getting the annotation's view by calling the mapView's viewForAnnotation method (not the same as the viewForAnnotation delegate method) and try animating it.

Answer (score 0):

[mapview deselectAnnotation:[mapview.selectedAnnotations objectAtIndex:0] animated:YES];

or

[mapview deselectAnnotation:calloutMapAnnotationView.annotation animated:YES];
where calloutMapAnnotationView is the callout bubble object of selected custm pin.